# how to retrieve "TextBox1" in gridview and indicate a value to it when aspx is load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, textbox, sqldatasource

Basically I want tO retrieve a "TextBox1" which I add in to one of the new column (TemplateField) of the gridview and the rest of the column are data load from the sqldatasource control

i will want to indicate the "TextBox1" basic value that i calculated...so the result is when the default.aspx is loaded (which mean page load) the "TextBox1" should have show the calculated value...sO now is how am I going to retrieve that " TextBox1" from the gridview in order for me to indicate a value

cause i dont need to use this code below as my gridview data is use the retrieve in sqldatasource in the design default.aspx

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Age");

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Name"] = "Chris Harris";
dr["Age"] = "40";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Name"] = "Sean Williams";
dr["Age"] = "39";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Name"] = "Paul Newcombe";
dr["Age"] = "38";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

SO how should do to retrieve that " TextBox1" from the gridview in order for me to indicate a value

```
<ItemTemplate>
                <table style="width: 73%; height: 31px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style1">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Calculation:"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this a row-by-row situation, you will probably want to do this in the `RowDataBound` event on the GridView:

```
public void gridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        Textbox txt = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("Textbox1");
        //Do your processing here...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to find control inside the gridview container in RowDatabound event . [Gridview class and methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w7ya1ts.aspx)

```
TextBox t = GridView1.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
            if (t != null)
            {
                t.Text = "Hello World!";
            }
```